# How can I have the centroid of each chunk of a catalog?

Tags: lidr

I use lidR package. I have a catalog and I want to save as a shapefile the centroid of each chunk make with opt_chunk_size of a catalog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but a combination of `lidR` functions and the [sf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/sf.pdf) package should work. Try the following:

```
ctg <- readLAScatalog("~/Documents/data/lidar/example_catalog/")
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 1000
plot(ctg, chunk=TRUE)
chunks <- catalog_makechunks(ctg)
library(sf)
centroids <- lapply(chunks, function(chunk) {
  return(st_point(x=c(chunk@center$x, chunk@center$y)))
})
centroids_shape <- st_as_sfc(centroids)
plot(centroids_shape)
st_write(centroids_shape, "/tmp/test.shp")
```

Plot of catalog:

[image]

Plot of un-chunked centroids:

[image]

Plot of chunked catalog:

[image]

Plot of chunked centroids:

[image]

Overlay of chunks, and their centroids:

[image]

** UPDATE ** - As mentioned by @[JRR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/103469/jrr), you will need version 3.0.0 of the `lidR` package to use `catalog_makechunks()` which I believe is currently in development. In older versions you must use the internal function `lidR:::catalog_makeclusters()`. To get version 3.0.0 of `lidR` you can run:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("Jean-Romain/lidR", ref = "devel")
```

Comment: This is a good answer. However `catalog_makechunks` exists only from v3.0.0 and is not "internal". It is exposed to users. Before v3.0.0 one must use `lidR:::catalog_makeclusters()` that is actually internal.